# How to catch F5 key pressed when the mouse is outside my page?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keypress

How can I catch the <kbd>F5</kbd> key press when the mouse is outside my page?

For example hovering on a scroll bar, or on an address bar, or on a menu etc.

Because in this case `e.which`, which usually contains `116` for <kbd>F5</kbd>, contains `undefined`

EDIT:
After playing with Alexey Lebedev' jsfiddle I discovered that if the last user click was inside my page, I actually can catch <kbd>F5</kbd>.

However if the last user click was outside my page, the problem remains.

I would think the browser client area is not in focus, but then it should not get the keypress and should not be refreshed at all.

Comment: In what browser and OS is this occurring?

Comment: Let's start from Windows 7/Chrome last version

Comment: I can't replicate it in Win7/Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/GRdGA/ (but make sure to click in the iframe first)

Comment: If your page isn't in focus, the key event will not be dispatched at it. You only might be able to catch `beforeunload`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the last user click is outside your page, for example in the address bar, it might still be a good idea to refresh the page on `F5`, but the page shouldn't be able to spy what URL you are typing, and thus shouldn't receive keyboard events.

If your goal is to prevent losing unsaved data on refresh, you can show a confirmation on `beforeunload`.

Comment: what I am trying to do is to understand which operation caused 'unload' event

Comment: AFAIK, you can't tell a click on 'Refresh' from closing the tab/window.